# Retrieve the complete details of a remote file without downloading it

Tags: php, curl, metadata, remote-access

How could I **extract** the **METADATA** / **METAINFO** / everything that would describe the **REMOTE FILE** without downloading it in the first place?

do you have some snippets in PHP?
how about in cURL?
or any language?

thanks

Comment: You can issue a HEAD request, which'll return SOME metadata about the file - basically it's a GET, but doesn't actually transfer the file, just the HTTP headers you'd get if you HAD done a get request.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to transfer some content to analyze it. Which filetype anyway?

Comment: "Everything" that describes a file is nothing short of the entire content of the file, so... the question is a bit vague. A HTTP HEAD request is the obvious thing to check out, I guess.

Comment: @mario If I downloaded a very little amount of the file, will it be enough to read the metadata?

Comment: I'm planning to write a script that will be applicable to any filetype, but for now the common filetypes only

Comment: @macki: If you don't answer my question, do you really expect a conclusive answer?

Comment: @mario did you not see my answer, I said ANY FILETYPE

Comment: Well, then the answer is: no. -- Also where did you get the idea that each file and type comes with embedded meta data?

Comment: I have no idea about it (at first)
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't get all the metadata from a file without downloading the entire file, as you have no way of knowing how much of the file you need before you've captured its metadata block, some file formats store metadata at the end of the file (meaning you'll need the entire file anyway), some files don't have any metadata embedded in them at all, and so on.

If you do a HEAD request, you will *usually* be able to get some basic metadata on the file in question in the form of the content-type and content-length headers returned by the server, but this is typically limited to the MIME type and the file size (and if you're dealing with a script that serves the file and that script doesn't set the necessary headers, you might not even get that).

Comment: how about if I downloaded a very small portion of the file, is the metadata found there?

Comment: Which part?  Like I said, you can't know where the metadata is within a file without downloading the entire thing. Some files have metadata at the beginning, some at the end, some don't have any at all.

Comment: I already said there's no way of knowing where in the file the metadata is located.  Just assuming it is at the start is no good.

Comment: have you found someone doing an algorithm for that?